# Raspberry pi zero ssh over usb in manjaro

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, manjaro

I want to connect to a raspberry pi zero (running raspbian lite) over ssh by using the ethernet over usb option. I've modified the `config.txt` and `cmdline.txt`, and create the `ssh`-file as described [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget), then connected the pi to my laptop using a mirco-usb-cable. The usb0-interface shows up as soon as the pi is plugged in, gets an Ipv6 and Ipv4 address, and I have configured the Ipv4-Method to Link-Local-Only.

However, I can't find the pi in the network. I did

```
ping raspberrypi.local
```

which returns an error `Name or service not found`.

I am running Manjaro Linux (the GNOME variant) as OS.

Comment: I'm going crazy about this, especially because I did the same successfully a year ago with an ubuntu OS. Or at least I think I did the same, somewhere has to be major difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is running into the same problem, it works now for me after I found [this incredible helpful solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=216968).

As some additional note: I got an error message after step 4: `avahi-resolve -n raspberrypi.local` saying that the daemon is not running. I solved this by starting the corresponding daemon

```
$ sudo systemctl start avahi-resolve.service
```